# What is the best way to remove duplicate objects from the Django database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

I am mining the Twitter Search API for tweets of a certain hashtag and storing them to a Postgresql database using the Django ORM.

Here is the code from my `tasks.py` file that handles this routine.

```
"""Get some tweets and store them to the database using Djano's ORM."""

import tweepy
from celery import shared_task

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


@shared_task(name='get_tweets')
"""Get some tweets from the twiter api and store them to the db."""
def get_tweets():
    tweets = api.search(
        q='#python',
        since='2016-06-14',
        until='2016-06-21',
        count=5
    )
    tweets_date = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_id = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_text = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]

    for i, j, k in zip(tweets_date, tweets_id, tweets_text):
        update = Tweet(
            tweet_date=i,
            tweet_id=j,
            tweet_text=k
        )
        update.save()
```

Here is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField()
    tweet_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tweet_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tweet_date) + '  |  ' + str(self.tweet_id)
```

I am getting duplicates, do to the Twitter API.

Is there a way to check for duplicates before the object gets save to the database. Here:

```
for i, j, k in zip(tweets_date, tweets_id, tweets_text):
        update = Tweet(
            tweet_date=i,
            tweet_id=j,
            tweet_text=k
        )
        update.save()
```

Is this something I can take care of in the extraction process here or is it something that I need to clean up afterward, like in the transformation phase?.

Comment: To what field are you refering when you say `duplicate` ?

Comment: The `tweet_id` needs to be unique, which I set to unique in the model, but when Celery tries to create new objects and save them to the database, it hangs with a key error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let your model manager do the job for you

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

for i, j, k in zip(tweets_date, tweets_id, tweets_text):
    try:
        Tweet.objects.create(
            tweet_date=i,
            tweet_id=j,
            tweet_text=k
        )
    except IntegrityError:
        log('duplicate tweet id {}'.format(j) 
        pass
```

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for. My first thought was an exception, but I didn't know what exception. Thanks.